# how to remove the character at which cursor is placed in an input box on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function remove() {

}
```

```html
<input id="input-box"></input>
<button onclick="remove()" id="remove-btn">remove</button>
```

I want to remove that specific letter at which cursor is placed in an input box on button click.

Comment: use `selectionStart` to find cursor position

Comment: Could you please explain the question more clearly

Comment: Tell me if i'm right, by clicking the button, you want to remove the character on which the cursor is on in an input box

Comment: You can get current cursor position from  ```selectionStart``` property of the input element, using that slice the current input value as you want and change the value of the input with sliced value

Comment: please can anyone explain me by editing the above code

Comment: yes, actually the character which is in front of that standing line cursor in an input box. just like when we use backspace key for removing a character in that google search bar. the only difference is this should be done by button click